# Classisthesis section numbers not showing

Tags: pdftex, classicthesis

I am using `classicthesis` with the MWE below.
When I compile locally, section numbers are not showing, but are included in the Table of Contents.
However, compiling with Overleaf *does* show the section numbers, both in the ToC and in the document.
So I think this is an issue with the version/compiler I am using to compile locally (`pdflatex` on Ubuntu-16.04).

How can I check which version of `classicthesis` is being called locally by `pdflatex`? And if it is out of date, how can I update it?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{First chapter}
    \section{First section}
        Hello, world
    
    \section{Second section}

\end{document}
```

Here is an image of how it looks when compiled locally:
[image: Missing section numbers.]

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! This [picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDoju.png) represents what I get from your example code.

Comment: Thank you! Yes that's what I get also on Overleaf. The problem is, when I compile locally, "First section" and "Second section" do not have section numbers preceding them.

Comment: That's quite curious. Can you please upload the log file you get from the local run?

Comment: I've uploaded the demonstration [here](https://github.com/flynnbr11/classicthesis_section_issue).

Comment: Oh! TeX Live 2015! You got the infamous `titlesec` bug! You should really upgrade your TeX system.

Comment: Indeed updating to TeXLive2020 has worked, thanks @egreg! 
Although now \subfile{} doesn't work so instead I'm using \input{}.
(If you want to post this as an answer I will accept it).